# Virtual network switcH required for android emulators in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I heard good things about new android emulators for Visual Studio 2015 / Windows 10 (thanks to Xamarin?), so just tried deploying to one and got a message that an internet connection is required so that the emulated device can connect to a virtual switch.

Is it me or does this seem peculiar to anyone else.

Anyone know the reason for this virtual network switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your VM for emulator. It should have Emulator Internal Network Adapter set to Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch. If you need an access to Internet from this emulator then check that also External Network Adapter is defined and it is set to the network card of your machine. If you are missing any of these press Add Hardware and add it manually.